# Is there a way to fix Recaptcha for ReactJS not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, axios, captcha

Im trying to add captcha to my react app and the front end works just fine as expected. but when the backend calls the api to verify the captcha response ([api](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify)) i get the following response `{ success: false, 'error-codes': [ 'missing-input-secret' ] }`.
Now when i log the request to see what data is being sent. i get this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esd09.jpg). as you can see the secret and response is being sent and my headers are correct but for some reason im getting an error.

heres my code:

```
const captchaRequest = await axios.post('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify', {
  secret: config.captchaSecretKey,
  response: captcha
}, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  }
});

const captchaResponse = captchaRequest.data;

if (!captchaResponse.success) {
  return res.status(401).json({
    message: 'captcha failed',
    success: false,
  });
}
```

If someone could please let me know what im doing wrong let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same problem. you have to send the data as parameters and not in the body.

```
const captchaResponse = await axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify',
  params: {
    secret: SECRET,
    response: CAPTCHA_RESPONSE
  }
});
```